# Loading custom font won't work

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to load a custom font to React Native but it just doesn't work.

I have the file `gerstnerbq_bold.tff` when I open it it says on the left top corner `Font name: Gerstner BQ` I put this file in `android\app\src\main\assets\fonts` and used this in the CSS `fontFamily: 'Gerstner Original Bold',` I did try every other combination for fontFamily but it just doesn't work.

I also restarted the server with react-native run-android but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was apparently because I was using `fontWeight`. When using `fontWeight` then `fontFamily` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I've actually had this issue before. Only *some* fonts have font weight enabled on android. If you use a font that doesn't then React-Native will use the default font.